# MyIntent in OnPostExecute isn't called and crashes my app?

Tags: android, android-intent

I notice this question have been asked before and i have tried a couple of suggestions just without success. It might be a typo thing or a scope issue but i can't find the problem. The quotes are being sent and the toast is also visible only the intent call isn't working.

Part of my QuoteFormActivity.java

```
private class AsyncHttpPost extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
    {       

        /*
        Context context;
        private AsyncHttpPost(Context context) {
            this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
        }
        */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params)   
        {           
            BufferedReader inBuffer = null;
            String url = "http://www.mydomain.com/submitted_quotes.php";
            String result = "fail";
            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
                List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text_quote", params[0]));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text_user", params[1]));

                UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                        postParameters);

                request.setEntity(formEntity);
            httpClient.execute(request);
            result="got it";

            } catch(Exception e) {
                // Do something about exceptions
                result = e.getMessage();
            } finally {
                if (inBuffer != null) {
                    try {
                        inBuffer.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return  result;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {       
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(QuoteFormActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            //Log.d("test_app","httppost thingy from private class: "+result);
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(QuoteFormActivity.this, DisplayQuoteActivity.class);
            //view.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //startActivity(new Intent(context, DisplayQuoteActivity.class));

        }   
    }
```

[EDIT (too long for a comment)] And this are the activities in manifest

```
<activity
        android:name="com.mydomain.quotes.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mydomain.quotes.DisplayQuoteActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_quote" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.mydomain.quotes.QuoteFormActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_quote_form"
        >

    </activity>
```

EDIT stack trace?

```
12-17 17:23:55.101: D/test_app(1554): Show Send Quote Page
12-17 17:23:55.981: I/Choreographer(1554): Skipped 75 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-17 17:24:16.091: I/Choreographer(1554): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-17 17:24:23.491: D/test_app(1554): Send quote form: test Afz: stack
12-17 17:24:23.902: D/dalvikvm(1554): GC_CONCURRENT freed 184K, 10% free 3059K/3364K, paused 73ms+113ms, total 277ms
12-17 17:24:24.542: D/test_app(1554): httppost thingy from private class: got it
12-17 17:24:24.981: D/AndroidRuntime(1554): Shutting down VM
12-17 17:24:25.021: W/dalvikvm(1554): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
12-17 17:24:25.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1554): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-17 17:24:25.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1554): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mydomain.quotes/com.mydomain.quotes.DisplayQuoteActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-17 17:24:25.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
12-17 17:24:25.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-17 17:24:25.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-17 17:24:25.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-17 17:24:25.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-17 17:24:25.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-17 17:24:25.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-17 17:24:25.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-17 17:24:25.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-17 17:24:25.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-17 17:24:25.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-17 17:24:25.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-17 17:24:25.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1554): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-17 17:24:25.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at com.mydomain.quotes.DisplayQuoteActivity.onCreate(DisplayQuoteActivity.java:30)
12-17 17:24:25.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-17 17:24:25.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-17 17:24:25.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-17 17:24:25.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1554):     ... 11 more
```

btw: in application design is this a good way to have a "thank you for submit", just redirecting the user to a selected activity.

Comment: is your asynctask an inner class of activity. post the stack trace

Comment: Agreeing with Raghunandan, a stack trace would be good. My best guess without more information is that DisplayQuoteActivity is not registered in your manifest.

Comment: I defined asynctask as an inner class of QuoteFormActivity which is basicly just a form. FYI: DisplayQouteActivity has been registered in the manifest.

Comment: hello, stack trace means the log? i have edit my question and added the log

Comment: Check my response, you are getting a NullPointer at your new Activity (DisplayQuoteActivity) at line 30, until you solve that null pointer reference, your activity will never work

Comment: The crash has nothing to do with the Activity, it's the NullPointerException in DisplayQuoteACtivity.onCreate() that is crashing, like @noni said. This is an ok way to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read your exception with more detail and you will find this:

```
DisplayQuoteActivity.onCreate(DisplayQuoteActivity.java:30) NullPointerException
```

Just check DisplayQuoteActivity at line 30, and you will find the problem why Android is not creating your new Activity. The startActivity code works fine!

Comment: You'll get the +50! As a newbie i don't even know how to properly read the log file and thanks to you i have fix my problem. Turns out i had a variable set from another activity in DisplayQuoteActivity. For furture learning how did you pick that particular line? Any tutorial suggestion on "reading the logfile"

Comment: Yes, using Android Studio you can read your logcat from there instead of using the Terminal (Mac OS) or Command Prompt. It provides you a Search Field where just simply writing "Exception" you will filter the entire logcat, and reading your last exception easily. Another thing, is that in some cases, you will find your exception "hidden" inside the stack trace. For example, if you just look at your Exception, first it says that Android cannot start new Activity, but if you keep reading, you fill find a "Caused by" that in most of the times its the real exception.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seem to be the way you trying to start your Activity. Try changing your `onPostExecute` to this:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {       
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(QuoteFormActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();

        QuoteFormActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(QuoteFormActivity.this, BuiltInCamera.class));
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }
```